# Sub-Functions In Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating a project which the user can call functions from my script. My goal is to try and make the syntax very clean. I would like to add a "sub function" for my script, to make the user's code more compact.

I'm already using a class for the script, so that wouldn't be an option.

Currently I've got this:

```
myDatabase.fetch("notes")
```

How can I make my syntax look more like this?

```
myDatabase.fetch("notes").where("theseNotes")
```

Here is another example:

```
firstFunction().secondFunction()
```

Comment: You're talking about [method chaining](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Explain-Python-class-method-chaining). Try having the methods return `self`.

Comment: Yes! That’s exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!